# Attach v-model to a dynamic element added with .appendChild in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with a library that doesn't have a Vue.js wrapper.
The library appends elements in the DOM in a dynamic way.

I want to be able to bind the `v-model` attribute to those elements with Vue and once appended work with them in my model.

I've done this in the past with other reactive frameworks such as Knockout.js, but I can't find a way to do it with vue.js.

Any pay of this doing?
It should be something among these lines I assume:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('v-model', '{{demo}}');
[VUE CALL] //tell vue.js I want to use this element in my model.

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Unfortunately manipulating DOM directly is not really possible with reactive frameworks like Vue :( I faced this myself when migrating an old jQuery app that was lazy-loading html from server. Have to change those html to json and feed to a Vue instance as objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper component for your library and then setup custom `v-model` on it to get a result on the lines of what you're looking for. Since your library is in charge of manipulating the DOM, you'd have to hook into the events provided by your library to ensure your model is kept up-to-date. You can have `v-model` support for your component by ensuring two things:

- It accepts a `value` prop
- It emits an `input` event

Here's an example of doing something similar: https://codesandbox.io/s/listjs-jquery-wrapper-sdli1 and a snipper of the wrapper component I implemented:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="listEl">
      <ul ref="listUlEl" class="list"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div v-for="variable in variables" :key="variable">
        {{ variable }}
        <input v-model="form[variable]" placeholder="Enter a value">
      </div>
      <button @click="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value", "variables", "template"],

  data() {
    return {
      form: {}
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.list = new List(
      this.$refs.listEl,
      {
        valueNames: this.variables,
        item: this.template
      },
      this.value
    );

    this.createFormModels();
  },

  methods: {
    createFormModels() {
      for (const variable of this.variables) {
        this.$set(this.form, variable, "");
      }
    },

    add() {
      this.$emit("input", [
        ...this.value,
        {
          id: this.value.slice(-1)[0].id + 1,
          ...this.form
        }
      ]);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    value: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.$refs.listUlEl.innerHTML = "";

        this.list = new List(
          this.$refs.listEl,
          {
            valueNames: this.variables,
            item: this.template
          },
          this.value
        );
      }
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // Do cleanup, eg:
    // this.list.destroy();
  }
};
</script>
```

Key points:

- Do your initialization of the custom library on `mounted()` in order to create the DOM. If it needs an element to work with, provide one via `<template>` and put a `ref` on it. This is also the place to setup event listeners on your library so that you can trigger model updates via `$emit('value', newListOfStuff)`.
- `watch` for changes to the `value` prop so that you can reinitialize the library or if it provides a way to update its collection, use that instead. Make sure to cleanup the previous instance if the library provides support for it as well as unbind event handlers.
- Call any cleanup operations, event handler removals inside `beforeDestroy`.

For further reference:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: Creating a whole wrapper around a library seems like a lot of work for such a simple thing. Isn't there anything more straight forward ?